# Is there way to remain the color of nav links if the hover cursor not in the element?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have problem regarding if my hover cursor not in the element the color back to white. is there way to make the nav links color remain if the hover cursor not in the hover elements? I will show you guys my output image that I have today. currently I use bootstrap for my navbar.

**Cursor not in the element**

[image: Cursor not in the element]

**I want to make the target output look like this.**

[image: Target output]

I will share to you guys my fiddle files for more details.

```css
.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border-top:5px solid #00BC54;
  color:black !important;

}

.dropdown a:hover {
  color:grey !important;
}

.nav-item:hover a {
  /*color:gray !important;*/
}

#navbarDropdown:hover {
  color:grey !important;
}

#navbarDropdown:focus {
  color:grey !important;
}
.navbar {
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}


.nav-item {
/*  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:8px;
  margin-right:50px;*/
   padding-top:10px;
   margin-right:60px;
  padding-bottom:8px;
}
.nav-item #navbarDropdown {
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color:#F9F9F9;

}

li.nav-item:hover div.dropdown-menu,
div.dropdown-menu:hover {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100000;

}

.nav-item #navbarDropdown:hover {
  color:#575a5d !important;
}

.nav-item #navbarDropdown:not(:hover) {
    color:white;
}
.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link  {
  font-weight:400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-dark custom-navbar-fixed" style="min-height: 56px; background-color:#575a5d !important; border-color:#575a5d !important; position:fixed; width: 100%; z-index:3;">
 <br><br>
 <button class="custom-toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  style="color:white !important;" data-target=".navbar1and2" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:white !important;"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar1and2" id="navbarSupportedContent2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" >
     <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           MEMBERSHIP
         </a>   
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#F9F9F9; box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); border-color:white; position: absolute; top:50px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:20px;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Benefits For</p>
                 <div style="border-right-style: dotted;  height:auto; "></div>
                  <a href="./physician_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important; "><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician</a>
                 <br><br>
                 <a href="./residents.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Residents & Fellows-in-Training</a>
                 <br><br>
                 <a href="./medical_students.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left;border-radius:  border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Students</a>
                 <br><br>
                 <a href="./international_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> International</a>
                 <br><br>
                 <a href="./affiliate_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Affiliate</a>

               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:20px;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Become a Fellow</p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: circle; ">
                 <li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Interested in becoming fellow?</a></li><br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Nominate a fellow <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:20px;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">For Members</p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                 <li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="far fa-gem"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Pay Dues <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
                 <br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Update Account <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
                 <br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-money-check"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; Check Orders <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"   role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           CME & MOC
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100 cme" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#F9F9F9; border-color:white; position:absolute; top:50px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

                <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">UNDERSTANDING MOC</p>
                <p>PSMID offers a number of resources to help members make sense of the MOC requirements and earn points.</p>
                 
                
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Understand MOC Requirements</a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Earn MOC Points</a>

               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                <p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Industry Leading Tools & Resources</p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none; ">
                 <li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"> MKSAP 18</a></li><br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/annals_icon.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Annals of IM </a></li>
                 <br>
                 <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-57x57.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Internal Medicine Meeting </a></li>
                </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">
                <br>
                <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                 <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
                </div>
                
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"   role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           MEETING & COURCES
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#F9F9F9; border-color:white; position:absolute; top:50px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

                <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-logo-350x115.png" class="img-fluid">
                <br><br>  
                <p style="font-size:18px; color:#8e908f;">The most comprehensive meeting in Internal Medicine.</p>
                <hr>
                
                <p style="font-size:27px; color:#8e908f;">Los Angeles,CA April 23-25, 2020</p>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> INTERNAL MEDICINE MEETING 2020</a>

               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                <p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Upcoming Internal Medicine Board Review Courses</p>
                <p style="font-size:20px; color:#8e908f">Prepare for the Certification and Maintenance of Certification (MOC) Exam with an PSMID review course.</p>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> BOARD CERTIFICATION REVIEW COURCES</a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> MOC EXAM PREP COURCES</a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">
                
                <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                 <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Internal Medicine Meeting</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">US Chapter Meetings</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">International Chapter Meetings</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Courses & Recordings</a>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Focused Topics</a>
                </div>
                
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           CLINICAL INFORMATION
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#F9F9F9; border-color:white; position:absolute; top:50px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

                <center>
                 <br>
                 <div style="line-height: 5px;">

                  <p style="font-size:30px;">PSMID Clinical Search</p>
                  <h5 style="font-size:20px;">Treating a patient? Researching a topic? Get answers now.</h5>
                   
             
           
            <div class="input-group  col-md-7">
          
           <input type="text" class="form-control" style="position: relative; top:7px; font-size: 15px; "  placeholder="Search Clinical Information" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
           <div class="input-group-prepend" style="position: relative; top:7px;  ">
             <span class="input-group-text"  id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #00A0DF !important; border-color:#00A0DF; color:white; "><i class="fas fa-search" style="font-size:15px;"></i></span>
           </div>

         </div>
         <br><br>
            <hr>

            <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
               <img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
               <br><br><br><br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT ANNALS</a>
               <br><br><br><br>
               <a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
               <img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
               <br><br><br><br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT MKSAP 18</a>
               <br><br><br><br>
               <a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
               <img src="./Assets/dmp_logo_v3.png" class="img-fluid">
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT DYNAMED PLUS</a>
               
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
       
            
                 </div>
                </center>
                

               </div>
               
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">
                
                <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                 <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Guidelines & Recommendations</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Performance Measures</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Journals & Publications</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Resources & Products</a>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">High Value Care</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Ethics & Professionalism</a>
                </div>
                
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>
       
 <!--       <li class="nav-item " style="padding-right:60px; color:white;">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#" >CLINICAL INFORMATION</a>
       </li> -->

         <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           PRACTICE RESOURCES
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#F9F9F9; border-color:white; position:absolute; top:50px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

                <p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Medicare</p>
                <p style="font-size:18px;">Ensure payment and avoid policy violations. Plus, new resources to help you navigate the Medicare Access and CHIP Reauthorization Act of 2015 (MACRA).</p>
                 
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare Resources</a>

               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                <p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Office Forms</p>
                <p style="font-size:18px;">Access helpful forms developed by a variety of sources for patient charts, logs, information sheets, office signs, and use by practice administration.</p>
                 
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Office Forms</a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6" style=" position: relative; top:10px;">
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                  <p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">QUICK LINKS</p>
                  <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                   <li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> QPP/MACRA </a></li>
                   <br>
                   <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>Physician & Practice Timeline </a></li>
                   <br>
                   <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Coding</a></li>
                   <br>
                   <li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Educator Resources</a></li>

                  </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                   <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
                   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
                   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
                   <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>

       <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           ADVOCACY
         </a>
        
      <div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400; background-color:#F9F9F9; border-color:white; position:absolute; top:50px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
                
             <br>
             <div style="line-height: 5px;">

              <p style="font-size:30px;">Where We Stand</p>
              <h5 style="font-size:20px;">PSMID advocates on behalf on internists and their patients on a number of timely issues. Learn about where PSMID stands on the following areas:</h5>
              
           
             </div>
             <br>
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Access to Care</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Patients Before Paperwork</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare and the Quality Payment Program</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicaid Reform</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Public Health</a>
               
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician Workforce and Team Based Care</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Women in Medicine</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Health Information Technology</a>
               <br><br>
               <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Liability Reform</a>
              </div>
             </div>
             <br>
               </div>
               
               <div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">
                
                <div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                 <p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Where We Stand</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Advocate Newsletter</a> <br><br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">State Health Policy</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Advocacy in Action</a>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Current Public Policy Papers</a> <br> <br>
                 <a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Policies & Recommendations</a>
                </div>
                
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item " >
         <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:white !important;"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> STORE</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this selector instead:

```
.dropdown:hover > a {
    color: #575a5d !important;
}
```

and get rid of the hover style for the a tag.

Since the dropdown menu is not a child of the a tag, you stop hovering on the a tag once you move your mouse down.

Instead, since the dropdown menu is a child of the .dropdown li, you can target the a tag whenever you're hovering inside of the .dropdown element or any of it's children.